# Unable to calculate formula value for Date type field using Java, Scala, Poi and Fillo

Tags: java, excel, scala, apache-poi

I am trying to read the date type value from excel sheet. Sample Excel -

[image]

Cell B2 is not a formula field.

B3 populated using `=RIGHT(B2,2)&"/"&MID(B2,5,2)&"/"&LEFT(B2,4)`

B4 populated using `=DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3))`

I am able to read B2 and B3 cell using below code -

```
object ReadExcelFile {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val xlsFilePath = "C:\\test.xlsx"

    val workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(xlsFilePath)))
    val sheet  = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1")

    val evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()
    //evaluator.evaluateAll()

    sheet.map(row => {
      row.map(cell => {
        val cellValue = readCellValues(cell, evaluator)
        print(cellValue + "\t")
      })
      println()
    })
    workbook.close()
  }

  def readCellValues(cell: Cell, evaluator: XSSFFormulaEvaluator): Any = {

    val dataFormatter = new DataFormatter()
    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
      evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell) match {
        case CellType.BOOLEAN => cell.getBooleanCellValue()
        case CellType.NUMERIC => {
          if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
            dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue())
          } else {
            cell.getNumericCellValue()
          }
        }
        case CellType.STRING => cell.getRichStringCellValue()
        case CellType.ERROR => cell.getErrorCellValue
        case CellType.BLANK => ""
        case CellType._NONE => ""
      }
    } else {
      dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)
    }
  }
}
```

**For B4 cell, I am getting junk value 15 and every time getting the CellType as ERROR**

I have tried `evaluator.evaluateAll()` but getting below exception -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval@cff1a53)

I have also tried `cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()` and `evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)` but no luck.

I have tried the Fillo library as well. Code -

```
Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
String xlsFilePath = "C:\\test.xlsx";
Connection connection=fillo.getConnection(xlsFilePath);
String strQuery="Select * from Sheet1";
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

while(recordset.next()){
    System.out.println(recordset.getField("Date"));
}

recordset.close();
connection.close();
```

Getting output -

```
20190726
26/07/2019
```

Is there any way to get the value of B4 cell without modifying the formula? I have to use the above-mentioned formula only.

Comment: Why not just read the cached cell value from the last time the formula was evaluated? Should be quicker and easier, assuming the formula value is up-to-date

Comment: I have tried this using cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(). Getting Error.

Comment: What error? Or do you mean you're getting a result type of error?

Comment: I am getting Error type and value is #VALUE!

Comment: If you open the file in excel, click into the cell, hit enter, then save the file, does that then read back as the right thing?

Comment: This solution is not feasible because I need to read the file from linux server and every time during read the excel, I need to read hundreds of file. So in linux server, I will not able to open the excel file from gui and if somehow I manage to open the file, it's not possible to manually open hundreds of file.

Comment: I'm not saying to do that every time, just once, so you can figure out where the problem lies

Comment: Still getting the Error type and #VALUE! after opened and saved the file.

Comment: But yet it shows the right value in Excel? That's most odd... Can you save as `.xlsx` (if not already), unzip, find the sheet xml, find the cell in question, and edit your question to post the XML of the cell in question?